# How to detect if the first character is a carriage return, and add carriage return

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, carriage-return

I have the value of a textarea, how do I find out if the textarea starts off with a carriage return? I read some posts and understand that the CR is represented as \n? But how can I find out if the very first thing (character?) in the textarea is a return? If not, how can I add one to it?

I'm picturing something like this:

```
var content = $("#myTextArea").val();

if (content.charAt(0)=="\n"){
//do nothing
}
else
{
content.before("/n")
}
```

Apparently it's wrong but how should I do it?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this. Is it for data format? You can always use [.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) and then add the carriage return to the beginning.

Comment: `content` is a string variable, it doesnt have a `before` method

Comment: `content = "\n" + content;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `before` inserts elements, it does not change the value of a textarea, you could do this

```
$("#myTextArea").val(function(_, v) {
    return (v.charAt(0) === "\n" ? "" : "\n") + v;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu77a83/)

Comment: Worked like charm thanks, but I'm just curious, I know v is the actual value, what does that underscore "\_" mean in "function(\_,v)"?

Comment: @photonacl - The first argument of the callback is the index, i.e. `1, 2, 3... ` etc. so I just used an underscore to get the second argument, and it's common to use an underscore when you don't need the argument for anything, it just shows that it's not needed for anything, but it still has to be there to access the second argument `v`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for :

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('myTextArea'); //Get the text area
if(textarea.value.charAt(0) !== '\n') // Check if the first char is not a newline
    textarea.value = '\n' + textarea.value; // Add a new line character.
```